# Extracting data from array in Yii 2

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I'm trying to get data from DB and show it in menu.

```
echo NavX::widget([
    'options' => ['class' => 'navbar-nav navbar-right'],
    'items' => [
        array_map(function ($model) {
            return [
                'label' => $model['param2'],
                'url' => ["/users/{$model['param3']}"],
            ];
        }, Model::find()->where(['userID' => 32])->asArray()->all()),
    ],
]);
```

But unfortunately this code is wrong, error says:

> Array to string conversion

Is there any other way to fix it ?

Comment: You try to echo an array there. Put a foreach around it and echo the items in the array.

Comment: I cannot because I user this code while building menu tree in yii2. There is NavX::widget([ with it's 'options, items etc...

Comment: Then plz show more code, that surrounds it.

Comment: Check main post again please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess, without testing:

```
echo NavX::widget([
    'options' => ['class' => 'navbar-nav navbar-right'],
    'items' => [
        array_map(function ($model) {
            return [
                'label' => $model['param2'],
                'url' => "/users/{$model['param3']}", // <--- string, not array!
            ];
        }, Model::find()->where(['userID' => 32])->asArray()->all()),
    ],
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the "Yii" way to do it will be using built-in `ArrayHelper`:

```
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;

...

$models = Model::find()->where(['userID' => 32])->asArray()->all();
$items = ArrayHelper::toArray($models, [
    'app\models\Model' => [    
        'label' => function ($model) {
            // Add label generation code here
        },
        'url' => function ($model) {
            // Add url generation code here
        }
    ],
]);
```

Then just pass the `$items` to your view with menu.

**Official docs:**

- [ArrayHelper::toArray()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-basearrayhelper.html#toArray%28%29-detail)

Comment: Show your code, especially how you are building `label` and `url`.

Comment: in label generation code I use - return $model['param2'];
But after all this code when I echo $items I get - Array to string conversion

Comment: Try without `asArray()`.